# SQL - After group by filtering down to rows where column value = certain string

Tags: sql, postgresql, having

Not sure why this isn't working.

When I run the query without `HAVING segment ilike 'Enterprise'` I get results (see screenshot) but when I add it back in the query returns nothing despite clearly containing instances where segment = 'Enterprise'. I can't find any instances online where `having` is used to filter for strings so I'm thinking this just isn't possible. Could someone confirm if this is the case and if there is an alternative method if so? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try using `LIKE` in place of `ILIKE`, or change `ilike 'Enterprise'` to `ilike 'enterprise'`.

Comment: I tried that to no avail

Comment: What about `ilike 'Enterprise%'`?

Comment: I get a syntax error whenever I try anything but =. I think @LuckyOwl is right and it's just for numeric filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use HAVING to filter for strings, you can only use it to filter for numeric values. To filter for strings, you'll need to use the WHERE clause.